# If one cell for each row from range A1:D50 is checked or has value>0, lock other cells in the row

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

How do I write the vba such that

if one cell for each row from range C14:F16 is checked or has value>0, lock other cells in the row.

And cell from range K14:K16 (Total) =

=0 if checkbox is checked

OR =cell D14:D16.value divide 30 if cell B2.value>0

OR =cell E14:E16.value divide 7 if cell C2.value>0

OR =cell F14:F16.value if cell D2.value>0

```
Sub Frequency()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("C14:F16")

Dim rng0 As Range, cell0 As Range, CheckBox As Object
Set rng0 = Range("C14:C16")

Dim rng1 As Range, cell1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("D14:D16")

Dim rng2 As Range, cell2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("E14:E16")

Dim rng3 As Range, cell3 As Range
Set rng3 = Range("F14:F16")

For Each cell In rng
    If Range("rng0").Object("CheckBox").Value = True Then
        cell0.Offset(0, 10).Value = 0
    ElseIf Range("rng1").cell1.Value >= 1 Then
        cell1.Offset(0, 9).Value = cell1.Value / 30
    ElseIf Range("rng2").cell2.Value >= 1 Then
        cell2.Offset(0, 8).Value = cell2.Value / 7
    ElseIf Range("rng3").cell3.Value >= 1 Then
        cell3.Offset(0, 7).Value = cell3.Value
    End If
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the code below is to answer your title question.
 The code ignore all the information in the "body" of the question.

Preparation:
All cells in the active sheet must be formatted as unlocked.
Each checkbox must have a name like this : "cbR02", "cbR03", "cbR04", and so on, where the last two digits of the name is the row where the checkbox reside. So in the example above, cbR02 located at row 2, cbR03 located at row 3 and cbR04 located at row 4.

```
Dim rg As Range: Dim nm As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set rg = Range("A2:D4")
If Not Intersect(Target, rg) Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveSheet
    If Target.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        .Unprotect
        Rows(Target.Row).Locked = True
        .OLEObjects("cbR" & Format(Target.Row, "00")).Enabled = False
        Target.Locked = False
        .Protect
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        .Unprotect
        Rows(Target.Row).Locked = False
        .OLEObjects("cbR" & Format(Target.Row, "00")).Enabled = True
        .Protect
    End If
    End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbR02_Click()
ProtectRow "cbR02"
End Sub
Private Sub cbR03_Click()
ProtectRow "cbR03"
End Sub
Private Sub cbR04_Click()
ProtectRow "cbR04"
End Sub

Sub ProtectRow(nm As String)
r = CInt(Right(nm, 2))
With ActiveSheet
If .OLEObjects(nm).Object.Value = True Then
    .Unprotect
    .Rows(r).Locked = True
    .Protect
Else
    .Unprotect
    .Rows(r).Locked = False
    .Protect
End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then MsgBox "Select one cell only"
End Sub
```

In the first sub, it create a range variable (rg) A2:D4, to detect if the value within is changed. If the value within rg is changed :

it check if the target cell is not empty and the value is numeric:
If yes then it unprotect the sheet, locked the rows of the target's row, disable the checkbox which reside in the target's row, unlock the target cell, protect the sheet.

else it check if the target cell is empty - it unprotect the sheet, unlocked the target cell and enable the checkbox reside in the target's row, protect the sheet.

The second to the fourth sub is to detect if the checkbox is changed, then it make a string with the name of the checkbox, then call the `ProtectRow()` sub.

In the `ProtectRow()` sub, it get's the row number where the changed checkbox reside as r variable. If the checkbox value = true, then it lock the whole r row, else it unlock the whole r row.

The last sub is to avoid a user select more than one cell.

Example:
A user tick the checkbox which located in row 2.
The whole row 2 then is locked. User won't be able to type to any column of row 2.
If the user want to type to a cell in row 2, he must untick first the checkbox. Then the entire row 2 is unlocked, enabling user to type at row 2.

A user type a number in cell D3.
Then the entire row 3 but cell D3 is locked, and also the checkbox which is located in row 3 is disabled. User won't be able to type in any column row 3 and he also won't be able to tick the checkbox located in row 3. He must clear what he type before in cell D3 in order he can type to another column row 3 or tick the checkbox located in row 3.

Please note, the rg variable must have a total rows the same as many as the checkbox on the sheet and the row number must the same with the name of the checkbox suffix.

Example it will throw error if the condition below meet :
rg = A2:D7 ---> total rows = 6
but the total of the checkboxes are not 6.

rg = A2:D7 ---> total rows = 6
the total of the checkboxes are also 6.
but the name of the checkbox is not cbR02 to cbR07 but something else.