# error438: Object doesn't support this property or method (OptionButtons in a Range)

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I'm trying to write the VBA so that in range H14:J16, for each row, if the Option Button in the left column is checked then cell.Offset(0,4).value=[a formula]; if option button in the middle column is checked then cell.Offset(0,3).value=[another formula]; if option button in the right column is checked then cell.Offset(0,2).value = [another formula]

[image]

I'm fairly new to VBA so am trying to piece together what I can and have come up with this so far:

```
Sub ServingSize()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("H14:J16")

Dim rng1 As Range, cell1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("H14:H16")

Dim rng2 As Range, cell2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("I14:I16")

Dim rng3 As Range, cell3 As Range
Set rng3 = Range("J14:J16")

For Each cell In rng
If Range("rng1").cell1.OptionButton = True Then
cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value * 0.5
ElseIf Range("rng2").cell2.OptionButton = True Then
cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
ElseIf Range("rng3").cell3.OptionButton = True Then
cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value * 1.5
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

What did i do wrong here?

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963751/if-one-cell-for-each-row-from-range-a1d50-is-checked-or-has-value0-lock-other

Answer (score 0):

You have to link a cell to each optionbutton, open the properties for the button , find the LinkedCell property and input the cell below the optionButton (it can be any other but for simplicity let's use the one located below the option button).

Then you use your code with modifications to test the linked cell value

```
Sub ServingSize()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("H14:J16")

Dim rng1 As Range, cell1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("H14:H16")

Dim rng2 As Range, cell2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("I14:I16")

Dim rng3 As Range, cell3 As Range
Set rng3 = Range("J14:J16")

For Each cell In rng
  If cell = True Then
    cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value * 0.5
  end if
Next cell
'repeat the loop for each range of linked cells with the particular formula for End Sub
```